# Is there any way to skip view creation in DBT?

Tags: view, dbt, dbt-mysql, dbt-postgres

I have DBT Project with around 42 models. In these 42 models, 23 are views (`materialized='view'`) and 18 are tables(`materialized='incremental'`).
The entire DBT Run takes time around 10 min. In these 10 min, 6 min are taken by View to create.

As per my understanding, these are logical views, so they should be created only once if not exists. Is there any way in DBT to skip the run of these view models every time so that overall time can be reduced from 10 min to 4 min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dbt exclude syntax combined with the materialization type should achieve this, for example:

```
dbt build --exclude config.materialized:view
```